# Keyboard problem in remote desktop session

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, keyboard

I have a very weird problem with one Windows XP installation: when connecting to a remote desktop (on Windows 2008 Server) to type in the at sign (@) it is necessary to press Ctrl-Alt-2 (on a spanish keyboard) when on local it is done with AltGr-2 and this doesn't work in the remote session.

To make this problem weird it seems that it is given but it is not sending to the application. To connect on webmail the user has to put in the mail account as user name and the username is always rejected. When copy/paste from the local session it is ok!?!.

Is there a possibility to re-install the remote desktop client? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known bug. Microsoft gives 2 solutions to solve this:

1. Use Ctrl + Alt instead of AltGR.
2. Change the configuration of the rdp client.

The solutions are detailled in Microsoft [KB 926934](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926934)